# Passing the encoding as third parameter is deprecated. Use an explicit zero offset

Tags: php, laravel

I just switched to the server from the localhost. It was working all fine until a few minutes ago. When I load the front page, this is the error It keeps showing up.

> mb_strrpos(): Passing the encoding as the third parameter is deprecated. Use an explicit zero offset (View:some-blade.blade.php)

Any idea what this error is trying to imply?

Error point directed

```
root/mainapp/vendor/thunderer/shortcode/src/Processor/Processor.php
```

In line 138,**139**,140:

```
 if($handler) {
        return call_user_func_array($handler, array($processed));
    }

    $state = $parsed->getText();
 *138*   $length = mb_strlen($processed->getTextContent(), 'utf-8');
 **139**  $offset = mb_strrpos($state, $processed->getTextContent(), 'utf-8');

 *140* return mb_substr($state, 0, $offset, 'utf-8').$processed->getContent().mb_substr($state, $offset + $length, mb_strlen($state, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8');
}
```

Comment: what is your laravel version, what is your php version?

Comment: @TsaiKoga PHP 7.4.2 and Laravel 5.6.39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using PHP 7.4, which has changed the number of arguments in `mb_strrpos()`. You need to pass the encoding as the **4th** parameter now.

See [Migration Guide for 7.4](https://www.php.net/migration74.deprecated#migration74.deprecated.mbstring)

> Passing the encoding as 3rd parameter to `mb_strrpos()` is **deprecated**. Instead pass a 0 offset, and encoding as 4th parameter.

---

**Sidenote**: It looks like this was not added to the changelog of the [mb_strrpos](http://php.net/mb-strrpos) documentation. So I have [updated the changelog list in the documentation here](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/phpdoc/en/trunk/reference/mbstring/functions/mb-strrpos.xml?r1=349048&r2=349047&pathrev=349048).

Comment: Thank you! 
To anyone wondering what I did: 
I passed an encoding as 0 in $offset. 
$offset = mb_strrpos($state,0, $processed->getTextContent(), 'utf-8');